# Levantamento anual

Tags: debate

A alguns dias atrás acessei o site e vi o link do "levantamento anual" do SOpt. Hoje fui acessar e não descobri onde ele está, se ele já saiu do ar ou alguma outra coisa ocorreu. 
Lembrei da medalha "Census" e descobri que varias pessaos ganharam ela a uma hora, que implica que o levantamento ainda está funcionando pra alguns. 
No SO original, ele está 'grudado'(pinned) no "em destaque no meta".

Alguma idea de onde está o link?

Não deveria ser mais promovido o levantamento?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_bedBQlMexcTr5WJ?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2018-collection&utm_term=link&award=c9bbd94d7a12409f9d21b387e280a265&site=stackoverflow.com

Comment: Só não tenho certeza se a medalha vem pra cá ou pro SOen.

Comment: @LINQ é pra ser sim. Vc foi o 1o. a ganhar aqui.

Comment: Mas é que eu cliquei no banner que tinha no site, este link do comentário eu acho que recebi por e-mail.

Comment: Obrigado, Vou dar uma olhada daqui a pouco :D

Comment: Mas é em inglês tb (já fiz o original)?

Comment: "You have either already completed the survey or your session has expired." 
Acho que ano que vem vou fazer via SOpt :P !

Comment: Mas Obrigado @LINQ !

Comment: Por nada, @Guto A pesquisa estava em inglês mesmo, o que mudou foi a medalha que foi ganha no SOpt